# How to sort an alphanumeric list by alphabet order

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, list, sorting

I am trying to sort an string list by country name which contains four digit number in front of each string elements. But, I actually get sorted by the numbers in front of each string instead of getting sorted by country name. Can anyone help me how to ignore the numbers in from of string while sorting. Thanks.

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("0003 India");
lst.Add("0005 America");
lst.Add("0004 Japan");
lst.Add("0001 Sweden");
lst.Add("0002 Germany");

lst.Sort();

lstSearchResult.DataSource = lst;
lstSearchResult.DataBind();
```

Output I am getting :

```
 0001 Sweden
 0002 Germany
 0003 India
 0004 Japan
 0005 America
```

I actually wanted output

```
 0005 America
 0002 Germany
 0003 India
 0004 Japan
 0001 Sweden
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `lst.Sort()` isn't working is because it is using the default Comparison of string - which takes the entire string to do the sorting. What you want to do is sort only by the part of the string after the space. To do so:

You can use Linq's `.OrderBy` method on the splitted second part of the string:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();

lst.Add("0003 India");
lst.Add("0005 America");
lst.Add("0004 Japan");
lst.Add("0001 Sweden");
lst.Add("0002 Germany");

lst = lst.OrderBy(item => item.Split(' ').ElementAtOrDefault(1)).ToList();

// Or if always by the string from position 5 onward then:
lst = lst.OrderBy(p => p.Substring(5)).ToList();

lstSearchResult.DataSource = lst;
lstSearchResult.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that there are aways four digits followed by a whitespace, you can use this [`Sort(Comparison<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) overload:

```
lst.Sort((s1, s2) => String.Compare(s1.Substring(5), s2.Substring(5), StringComparison.Ordinal));
lstSearchResult.DataSource = lst;
lstSearchResult.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to already suggested Linq queries and Lambda expressions, you can write your own implementation of `IComparer<T>`:

```
private class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return x.Substring(5).CompareTo(y.Substring(5));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// you can also declare this as static for your class or application
var comparer = new MyComparer();

// actual sorting:
lst.Sort(comparer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Split` in `OrderBy` and specify the part you would like to sort on.

```
lst.OrderBy(x=>x.Split(' ')[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the digits 000# are always 4. You could do something like this:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("0003 India");
lst.Add("0005 America");
lst.Add("0004 Japan");
lst.Add("0001 Sweden");
lst.Add("0002 Germany");

lst = lst.OrderBy(p => p.Substring(5)).ToList();

    lstSearchResult.DataSource = lst;
    lstSearchResult.DataBind();
```